# How to render component as text in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Can somebody help me to render Text from a component from a function? This is my case. I have a function to hightlight a custom character in a string. The function is like this.

```
 highlight = (string) => {
    var re = new RegExp('ABC', 'g')
    var result = string.replace(re, <Text style={{ fontWeight : 'bold' }}>ABC</Text>)
    return(
        <Text>{result}</Text>
    )
}
```

Then, in render function of my class, I call this function like this:

```
 <Text style={{marginBottom: 10}}>
    {this.highlight('ABC DEF GHI')}
 </Text>
```

The goal is, I want to give bold `ABC` from `ABC DEF GHI`. But when I run this, the result is like this : [object Object] DEF GHI.. Can somebody help me so the result is **ABC** DEF GHI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The words will always be separated by a blank space? If so, I would do a solution like this:

```
{
  'ABC DEF GHI'.split(" ").map(
      s => s.match('ABC', 'g') ? 
        <Text style={{ fontWeight : 'bold' }}>{s}</Text> : 
        <Text>{s}</Text>)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The **[object Object]** is actually the error statement which is caused by this line in your code

```
 var result = string.replace(re, <Text style={{ fontWeight : 'bold' }}>ABC</Text>)
```

Now your result variable become and object as **string.replace(re, `<Text style={{ fontWeight : 'bold' }}>ABC</Text>`)** return error.
this is because second argument of replace must be string else it will give unexpected token... error.

 to solve this You can do this

```
  highlight = (string) => {
    var boldString = "ABC"
    var re = new RegExp(boldString, 'g')
    var result = string.replace(re,"")
    return{
        boldText:boldString,
        regularText:result
     }

}
```

and in your render function

```
<Text style={{marginBottom: 10}}>
    <Text style={{ fontWeight : 'bold' }}>{this.highlight("ABC DEF GHI").boldText}</Text>
    {this.highlight('ABC DEF GHI').regularText}
 </Text>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's look like it only work for "ABC" in front of the string. Not in random place in a string